# Reset column order in angularjs ui-grid after moving

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I have a ui-grid using the ui-grid-move-columns directive. With this directive, I can drag drop the ui-grid columns to change their order. I would like to be able to reset the column order back to the original state.

Without the ui-grid-move-columns directive you can reorder the options.columnDefs to change the column order. In this case, changing the order of the options.columnDefs seems to have no immediate effect. I found that I could clear the columnDefs, and then re-populate, but this caused other issues, and also seems a bit hacky (see plunker for example http://plnkr.co/edit/JUqzefRKJgoF0VQXrffa?p=preview):

```
$scope.reset = function(){
  var columnDefs = $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs;
  var columnDefsBak = columnDefs.slice();
  columnDefs.length = 0;
  $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN );
  columnDefs.push.apply(columnDefs, columnDefsBak)
  $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN );
}
```

I also tried using the ui.grid.moveColumns.moveColumn(originalPosition, finalPosition) API (http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.moveColumns.api:PublicApi), and re-ordering everything, but for a wide table (approx 20 cols, and needing to move 19 of them) the performance in FF and IE was terrible.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by modifying the grid.moveColumns.orderCache array. This is not a documented public API, so this solution should be used with caution.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
      gridApi.core.on.rowsRendered($scope,function(){
        if(!$scope.initialColumnOrder)
          $scope.initialColumnOrder = $scope.gridApi.grid.columns.slice();
      });
    }
  };

$scope.reset = function(){
  if($scope.initialColumnOrder) {
    var columnDefsColMov = $scope.gridApi.grid.moveColumns.orderCache;
    columnDefsColMov.length = 0;
    columnDefsColMov.push.apply(columnDefsColMov, $scope.initialColumnOrder)
    $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN);
  }
}
```

See here for a complete example - http://plnkr.co/edit/x0ogsvQhj6kpLVqcxPhF?p=preview